# Upgrade okular in debian wheezy

Tags: upgrade, debian, okular

I have okular version 0.14.3 with KDE 4.8.4. I use debian wheezy and I dont know how I can upgrade to 0.15 version of okular.

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question as you ask for 0.15, but the latest stable version of `okular` is 0.17.

The instruction to download and compile `okular`are very clear and can be found [here](http://okular.kde.org/download.php).

Comment: +1 But @lepto, you should note that compiling from source will require you upgrade several libraries on your system to be compatible with the new Okular version. Most notably, you'll have to upgrade libpoppler.